# Different users and rules in Wordpress or Joomla

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I am going to make a website which there is 3 type of users.

Admin
    - can CRUD posts

Teacher
    - can CRUD own posts in their's own pages.

Student
    - can Read posts, comment, ...

I know how to do this in PHP, but I need to implement this website with Wordpress OR Joomla.
Can Wordpress/Joomla provide my needs or I have to install extra plugins.
If I need plugins, would you please tell me plugin's names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with Joomla default features.

Super Administrator would have full access to administrator panel and all articles.

Then you have to create Authors that could have access to their own articles (this is the full list of [privileges](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:How_permissions_work_in_Joomla!_2.5#Permissions_to_do_things:_Access_Control) in Joomla).

As for students you have to find a [comments extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/articles-comments).

Good Luck!